# Scala - How to list 2 parameters of a vector of an object?

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to Scala. I've been searching all day for this. I'm trying to get a vector of names from another vector that contains objects with said name.

To rephrase it properly : I have points, 2 points create a segment ("from" point and "to" point), multiple segments create a path. Now, what I'm trying to do is to list the points inside a path, the said path in parameter.

So far, I've managed to create the entities and come up with this function :

[Get all the "From" points from a path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp6jZ.png)

The problem is that I can't get the last point, as it only lists the "from". Is there an easy way around that?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that the first `path(n).to == path(n + 1).from` etc?

If so:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def getPoints(points: List[Element]): List[Point] = points match{
  case Nil => Nil
  case e :: Nil => List(e.from, e.to)
  case x :: xs => x.from :: getPoints(xs) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, both helped me to achieve what I wanted!

Comment: Updated to fix slight bug,

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly work with your stopsInPath() function and with the creative recursion answer given. I will add that this is an excellent problem by which you can learn some of the powerful functional programming techniques available already in the  Scala core library: namely, the use of flatMap() to transform an instance of a type that contains one type into an instance of that same type containing another, entirely different type. The goal is to formally define the transformation and to handle any errors. In this case, we transform a Vector of Segments into a Vector of Points. You can find on this site and others much useful information on functional theories (monads, et al.) but the basic idea of a monad (etymology: "irreducible singularity") is to transform Vector[A] into Vector[B], where side-effects and errors are explicitly defined and handled and A and B can be quite a range of things, but the containing type, in this case, Vector, remains the same. Now, to the code:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
case class Segment(from: Point, to: Point)
val path: Vector[Segment] = Vector(Segment(Point(1,2),Point(2,4)), 
  Segment(Point(3,6), Point(4,8))) 
val points: Vector[Point] = path.flatMap{seg => Vector(seg.from, seg.to)}
```

yields:

points: Vector[Point] = Vector(
  Point(1, 2),
  Point(2, 4),
  Point(3, 6),
  Point(4, 8)
)

I could have omitted the explicit type definitions `val path: Vector[Segment]` and `val points: Vector[Point]`, letting type inference shorten the code to `val path = ...` and `val points = ...`

, but I left them in to clarify my point: the transformation from Vector[Segment] to Vector[Point].

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your answer is perfectly clear and helped a lot!